# ExtJS how to prevent DomHelper from generate element id

Tags: extjs4

When using Ext.DomHelper.append() method to generate html markup it sometime generate id attribute for the element, how can I prevent that from happen?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to supply your own ID through the `id:` config option. Ext.Element needs any DOM element it wraps to have an ID, so it will automatically create one whenever it touches a DOM element that doesn't already have one

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.DomHelper.append()` returns [`Ext.Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element) by default. Ext.Element is wrapper for DOM node and Extjs adds id for corresponding node automaticaly while wrapping.

You can pass `false` as the third param and then `Ext.DomHelper.append()` will return DOM node instead of Ext.Element:

```js
Ext.core.DomHelper.append(
    Ext.getBody(),
    {tag: 'div', html: 'bla'},
    false // this is required in order to return DOM node instead of Ext.Element
  );
```